# Обрезать текст до символа "\"

Tags: javascript

Очень коротко:
есть 2 формы. При изменении значения поля `file` в Форме №1, стоит обработчик, который это значение записывает в другое поле в Форме №2. Ну не суть.

Получаем значение типа: `C:\fakepath\document.doc`

Вопрос: как обрезать значение в текстовом поле до знака `\`, чтобы получить в поле только `document.doc`?

Comment: Эта часть стандартная? `C:\fakepath`?

Comment: я думаю будет постоянная, но пока не уверен. А можно с 2мя вариантами?)) где постоянная ,а  где нет. Я так понимаю идея обрезать с начала по кол-ву символов? А есть варианта с конца до знака "\"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью `lastIndexOf` + `substring` :

```js
var a = 'C:\\fakepath\\document.doc';
var b = a.lastIndexOf('\\');

var c = a.substring(b + 1);

console.log(c);
```

Comment: На этой строке не работает `C:\fakepath\document.doc`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan но она же в сниппете, и работает

Comment: Проверили вы это?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ну да, вот даже проверил в консоли в ИЕ 8, работает...

Comment: И почему же я проверяю вот и сейчас и оно не работет

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan [ссылка 1](http://prntscr.com/gyevmk)  [ссылка 2](http://prntscr.com/gyew48)

Comment: все получилось, @RazmikGalstyan вы lastIndexOf один слыш или два пишите? я написал как в примере и все норм